# TSQL random sample

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, random

I need to select a random sample using TSQL from a table based on ratios of 2 different variables in the table.

The random sample required is approximately 8000 records from a table with about 381,000 records. The random sample must have approximate ratios of 2 variables:

4:1 (Male/Female) - 2 category variable
4:3:2:1 (Heavy/Moderate/Light/Very Light) - 4 category variable

Comment: Show some sample data and table structure.

Answer (score 3):

Break it down to how many of each

```
select top (640) * 
from table 
where sex = 'f' 
  and cat = 'heavy' 
order by NewID() 
union all
select top (480) * 
from table 
where sex = 'f' 
  and cat = 'medium' 
order by NewID()  
...
```

4 + 1 = 5
4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10
640 = 8000 / 5 * 4 / 10

Comment: 640x480 ... I'm getting the sense you are a photo hound.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti If you do the math those are the actual values.

Comment: Happy coincidence then.  Knew they were close, but didn't have the energy to do the math :)